# "fetch type out of range" error message throwing

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-2010

While executing the following code `szNotes                := SQL.FieldByName('Notes').AsString;` throwing an "fetch type out of range" error message. I'm using SQL Server DB, the field type is `VARCHAR(MAX)`. How to resolve this issue, please guide me.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using and what data type is `SQL`?

Comment: Delphi 2010, and Data type in SQL is `varchar(MAX)`

Comment: Ok for D2010 but the data type for SQL is probably a TTable, TADODataSet, TClientDataSet or something like that. Some descendant from TDataSet? Do you use dboGO or BDE or dbExpress or ....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use szNotes := SQL.FieldByName('Notes').AsWideString;

Comment: which type of the variable "szNotes" in Delphi?

Comment: `WideString` variable is using in Delphi2010

Comment: i am also using MS SQL table with field type varchar(max) and delphi variable widestring, so my code works.      ` procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: widestring;
  Aqry: TADOQuery;
begin
  Aqry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  with Aqry do
  begin
    Connection := ADOConnection1;
    SQL.Text := 'select value from test Where id = 1';
    Open;
    S := Aqry.FieldByName('value').AsWideString;
    ShowMessage(s);
  end;
end;`